# Discord Bot won't reply when prefix being set to more than 1 character

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working with the bot database, and everything works well but when I set the prefix to something more than two characters, the bot won't reply. Help?

**So here's my 'prefix.js' code**

```
    let newPrefix = args[0];

    if (await Prefix.findOne({
        guildID: message.guild.id
      })) {
      let guildPrefixes = await Prefix.findOne({
        guildID: message.guild.id
      });
      if (!guildPrefixes) {
        guildPrefixes = await new Prefix({
          _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
          guildID: message.guild.id,
          prefix: newPrefix,
        })
        await guildPrefixes.save();
        message.channel.send(`Successfully set the guild Prefix to ${newPrefix}!`);
      } else if (guildPrefixes) {
        await Prefix.findOneAndUpdate({
          guildID: message.guild.id,
          prefix: newPrefix,
        });
        return message.channel.send(`Successfully updated the guild Prefix to ${newPrefix}!`);
      }
    }
  }
```

**And here's my messageEvent**

```
let guildPrefixes = await Prefix.findOne({
      guildID: message.guild.id
    });

    if (message.content.startsWith(guildPrefixes.prefix)) {
      const [cmdName, ...cmdArgs] = message.content
        .slice(client.prefix.length)
        .trim()
        .split(/\s+/);
      const command = client.commands.get(cmdName);
      if (command) {
        command.run(client, message, cmdArgs);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try logging the prefix it gets, and check if it matches what you set up as the prefix. If it doesn't, check what is saved to the database.

Comment: I have tried both ways and it shows the exact same Prefix that I wanted it to change to ("!!"). I even tried "--" but still not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your response to my comment on the question it looks like on line 7 of the message event code you have a static prefix:

```
.slice(client.prefix.length)
```

I suppose it is probably something like ! or ?, so the length is 1. When you try to set it to `!!`, and then run `!!test`, `cmdName` will be `!test` because you slice off 1 character (the static prefix), which is not a command. Try changing the static prefix in the slice to the dynamic one:

```
.slice(guildPrefixes.prefix.length)
```

Your message event should look like this:

```
let guildPrefixes = await Prefix.findOne({
  guildID: message.guild.id
});

if (message.content.startsWith(guildPrefixes.prefix)) {
  const [cmdName, ...cmdArgs] = message.content
    .slice(guildPrefixes.prefix.length)
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/);
  const command = client.commands.get(cmdName);
  if (command) {
    command.run(client, message, cmdArgs);
  }
}
```

Hope it works

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I modified a little to `guildPrefixes.prefix.length` but still thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped, fixed the code I provided (I'm not really a visual coder, I have to run stuff to see if they work, so mistakes like this happen to me).